# JQuery Mobile Popover outside of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to have a global popover with some alerts in it in jQuery Mobile.  Is that possible?  It seems like the popover has to be in a jquery mobile page for it to be accessed.  I'm assuming it's because everything outside of that page isn't visible.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about.  How do I get the second version to work?

Works

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="content">

        <a href="#alert-popup" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Popup with close button right</a>

        <div data-role="popup" id="alert-popup" data-theme="c">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
            <h1>Alert Title</h1>
            <p>
                Freegan thundercats raw denim adipisicing elit. 8-bit hella lomo do irony, sartorial aliquip wes anderson. Elit quinoa consectetur hoodie, bushwick 3 wolf moon godard eiusmod next level quis echo park. Keytar ullamco exercitation salvia, brunch before they sold out cray minim echo park polaroid vegan cliche reprehenderit vero synth. Artisan VHS fanny pack aliqua ex williamsburg duis. Reprehenderit chillwave skateboard post-ironic, food truck ethical est wes anderson letterpress incididunt master cleanse. Selvage farm-to-table elit vinyl jean shorts, consectetur delectus non banksy.
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Doesn't work

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="content">

        <a href="#alert-popup" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Popup with close button right</a>

    </div>
</div>



<div data-role="popup" id="alert-popup" data-theme="c">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <h1>Alert Title</h1>
    <p>
        Freegan thundercats raw denim adipisicing elit. 8-bit hella lomo do irony, sartorial aliquip wes anderson. Elit quinoa consectetur hoodie, bushwick 3 wolf moon godard eiusmod next level quis echo park. Keytar ullamco exercitation salvia, brunch before they sold out cray minim echo park polaroid vegan cliche reprehenderit vero synth. Artisan VHS fanny pack aliqua ex williamsburg duis. Reprehenderit chillwave skateboard post-ironic, food truck ethical est wes anderson letterpress incididunt master cleanse. Selvage farm-to-table elit vinyl jean shorts, consectetur delectus non banksy.
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, please see [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html):

> A popup div has to be nested inside the same page as the link.

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#alert-popup" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Popup with close button right</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="alert-popup" data-theme="c">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
        <h1>Alert Title</h1>
        <p>
            Freegan thundercats raw denim adipisicing elit. 8-bit hella lomo do irony, sartorial aliquip wes anderson. Elit quinoa consectetur hoodie, bushwick 3 wolf moon godard eiusmod next level quis echo park. Keytar ullamco exercitation salvia, brunch before they sold out cray minim echo park polaroid vegan cliche reprehenderit vero synth. Artisan VHS fanny pack aliqua ex williamsburg duis. Reprehenderit chillwave skateboard post-ironic, food truck ethical est wes anderson letterpress incididunt master cleanse. Selvage farm-to-table elit vinyl jean shorts, consectetur delectus non banksy.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mqZzd/)**

Comment: If you can explain a bit about what you're wanting it for exactly then I can try to help you think of some options, but as far as I can tell from reading the docs, the div has to be inside the same page.

Comment: I was trying to have a common popup in the bottom template for each page, so that they can all access it.  I'm achieving that with a dialog with an adjusted close button for now.

Comment: I was thinking that you may be able to append it via jQuery then call the `.open()` method on it when the button is pressed, but you're probably just better off leaving it on each page. If I come across any better solutions then I'll post them here and would greatly appreciate it if you did the same. Apologies for not being much more help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as of right now the popover has to live in the same page or the same data-role="page" div (if you're creating a multi-page site in one file). To get around this I put a placeholder popover on each page and populate that with some JS when the site is loaded (or if you want every time the menu button is clicked).

Below is a basic example, you can get the full details here (including a little script on disabling the menu option for the current page the user is on: http://fromdehart.tumblr.com/post/35555011698/jquerymobile-included-popup-menus-for-multipage-site

or download or Fork the full code on GIT here: https://github.com/fromdehart/jQueryMobile-Included-Popup-Menus/

```
<!— Popup Placeholder —>
<div data-role=“popup” id=“lMenu” data-overlay-theme=“a” class=“ui-content” data-position-to=“window”>
    <a href=”#” data-rel=“back” data-role=“button” data-theme=“a” data-icon=“delete” data-iconpos=“notext” class=“ui-btn-right”>Close</a>
    <!—create a list where we can populate the menu—>
    <ul data-role=“listview” class=“leftMenu”></ul>
</div>
```

JS for creating and posting the menu

```
function leftMenu() {
  output = ””;
  //html for menu list items
  output += ‘<li><a data-transition=”slide” href=”#home”>Home</a></li>’;
  output += ‘<li><a data-transition=”slide” href=”#taryn”>Taryn</a></li>’;
  output += ‘<li><a data-transition=”slide” href=”#flula”>Flula</a></li>’;
  //write html into any items with the <ul> with the class of “leftMenu”
  $(‘.leftMenu’).html(output);
 //Targeting a class allows us to input the code in multiple places rather than an ID where it will only effect the first instance of that ID
}
```

Back in the HTML at the before the close of the body we’ll call the menu function

```
  <script type=“text/javascript”>leftMenu();</script>
</body>
```

Comment: What's different compare to the actual accepted answers? Could you point out just those points? Regards.